# If a law changes very recently, is there a grace period due to not knowing the new law change?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

I was recently watching a video of a police officer who lied to a driver that "a new law passed" that allows police officers to stop someone from recording. The driver was an attorney and knew better.

I was curious about this situation where a law changes that you may not be aware of because it only very recently passes. It seems wrong that someone who may have been not aware it was recently changed would be punished. I imagine it depends on the severity of the law, but is there some sort of grace period due to information not travelling fast enough?

While I think the above scenario is a little extreme, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: As a new contributor it would be great if downvotes were accompanied by a reason for the down vote.

Comment: I regret to inform you that this will almost certainly not happen. There's are a few people just doling out downvotes on what appears to be a random basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many laws state a date on which they go into effect, often several months or a few years after they are passed. But this is the choice of the legislature in each specific case, and there is no requirement to provide a grace period. Some laws go into effect at once when they are passed.

Comment: Not "when they are passed" - when they are signed by the Governor/President.

Comment: "Passed" is generally understood to mean that a bill has been signed or otherwise enacted.